# feh can't display image

Tags: python, image

I have written a python script that displays the image from the URL.

```
def image_func(link_image):
    img_cmd = "feh -F %s" %(link_image)
    os.system(img_cmd)
    os.system("pkill feh")
```

If I run the python program directly using

```
python main.py
```

it runs without any issue.

**But if I run from the .service file .. it throws this error.**

```
feh ERROR: You have no HOME, cannot read themes
```

I am running this from the root terminal rather than the user terminal.

**.service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=My device boot script service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
user=user1
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Restart=always
ExecStart=/root/MediaPlayer/venv/Include/start.sh > /dev/null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Error message says you have o 'HOME' environment variable set. Is 'user1' a valid user? Several confusing elements here. You're running as 'user1', but running a script saved in 'root' user directory. You're starting a bash script, but your code is in a python script. What is the relation between the two? And it looks like you're using a virtual environment. Are you sure that is initialised when you start your python script?

Comment: user1 is a valid user. the start.sh script executes the python program

Comment: I would add some debug code to your bash / python scripts to show / save the environment, since that seems to be the problem area

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why do you use `Type=idle`. `Man systemd.service` says:

> Note that this type is useful only to improve console output, it is not useful as a general unit ordering tool ...

As far as I know you do not have any console output so this option seems to be unnecessary. You want to output graphics as far as I understand to display an image. Usually you can do this only `After=graphical.target`. The service is missing a HOME variable. In respect of the comments from *@Dirk* you are running your **python** script (not a bash script) as root from the command line. You should do exactly the same within the unit. By default *root* is used for executing. There is also no suppressing of (error) messages with redirection to `/dev/null` so you can look with `journalctl -b -e` if there are some messages from the python script. I would configure your unit as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=My device boot script service
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution .. but still the same issue.

Comment: @ron123456 I have updated my answer. Please give me feedback if it runs.

Comment: @ron123456 Do you get some error messages with `systemctl status deviceboot.service` and `journalctl -e --unit=deviceboot.service`, or what the name of your device is?